# Monaco Editor - execute custom functions when 'ctrl+click'

Tags: monaco-editor

I need to simulate a link behaviour in monaco-editor:

- When holding CTRL the line should be underlined.
- When clicking the mouse a custom method should be executed.

Is there any way to achieve it?

thanks!